# Copy images from one folder to another using their names on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, shell, shutil

I have a pandas dataframe that consists of 10000s of image names and these images are in a folder locally.

I want to filter that dataframe to pick certain images (in 1000s) and copy those images from the aformentioned local folder to another local folder.

Is there a way that it can be done in python?

I have tried to do that using `glob` but couldn't make much sense out of it.

I will create an sample example here: I have the following df:

```
img_name
2014.png 
2015.png 
2016.png 
2021.png 
2022.png 
2023.png
```

I have a folder for ex. "my_images" and I wish to move "2015.png" and "2022.png" to another folder called "proc_images".

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import os
import shutil

path_to_your_files = '../my_images'
copy_to_path = '../proc_images'

files_list = sorted(os.listdir(path_to_your_files))
file_names= ["2015.png","2022.png"]

for curr_file in file_names:
    shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(path_to_your_files, curr_file),
                    os.path.join(copy_to_path, curr_file))
```

Something like this ?